# Combine subject and observer in a single subscribe RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I have an Behavior Subject

```
private usersSubject: BehaviorSubject<ActionedUser[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
public usersChange: Observable<ActionedUser[]> = this.usersSubject.asObservable();

constructor() { }

set updatedUsers(users: ActionedUser[]) {
    this.usersSubject.next(users);
}
```

and an Observable

```
getCurrentUser(): Observable<WebAuthUser> {
    if (environment.production) {
        return this.http.get<WebAuthUser>(`${this.webAuthURL}/wauth/api/user`, { withCredentials: true });
    }
    const devUser: WebAuthUser = {
        userName: 'local_dev_user',
    };

    return of(devUser);
}
```

i want to join them into a single subscribe but for some reason when i use forkJoin() and subscribe to it nothing is being emitted

```
 forkJoin([
        this.saveUsersSubject.usersChange,
        this.api.getCurrentUser(),
    ]);
    this.getUsersDataAndLoggedUserSubscription.subscribe(([ userData, loggedUser]) => {
        
        this.actionedUsers = userData;
        this.currentUser = loggedUser;
    });
```

i think that it is due to the Subject but what can be the best way to join them and provide value once both are done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1: reactive method (IMO elegant)

`forkJoin` would only emit when both observables complete. The quickest way would be to tack in a `take(1)` to the `BehaviorSubject` observable. But this assumes you do not need the future emissions from the `BehaviorSubject`. If you wish to react to each emission of the `BehaviorSubject`, then you could use `combineLatest` or `zip` (note: they aren't synonymous) instead of `forkJoin`.

```js
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

forkJoin([
  this.saveUsersSubject.usersChange.pipe(take(1)),
  this.api.getCurrentUser()
]);
```

#### Option 2: synchronous method (IMO inelegant)

As opposed to `Subject` and `ReplaySubject`, `BehaviourSubject` contains a special trait that it "holds" the last value pushed to it. You could access it anytime synchronously using the the `value` getter or the `getValue()` method (both essentially serve the same purpose).

```js
private usersSubject: BehaviorSubject<ActionedUser[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
public usersChange: Observable<ActionedUser[]> = this.usersSubject.asObservable();

constructor() { }

set updatedUsers(users: ActionedUser[]) {
  this.usersSubject.next(users);
}

public actionedUsers(): ActionedUser[] {
  return this.usersSubject.value;
}
```

```js
this.api.getCurrentUser().subscribe({
  next: (currentUser: any) => {  
    this.actionedUsers = this.saveUsersSubject.actionedUsers();
    this.currentUser = loggedUser;
  },
  error: (error: any) => {
    // handle errors
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much i used combineLatest as such and it solved my problem:



combineLatest([this.saveUsersSubject.usersChange, this.api.getCurrentUser()])
   .subscribe(([userData, loggedUser]) => {
    this.userDetails = userData;
    this.currentUser = loggedUser; },
   );